# Pushing data into the cloud with android

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am trying to push some sensor data from android onto the cloud. There seems to be certain existing sites like xively, thingsspeak,nimbits which do all of this. But the thing is I need to be able to dynamically create new devices without logging into the site and also push data from the android phone to those sites. I can do the latter easily but the former seems to be an area where there is a lot of restriction. I also need to describe my sensor data very accurately so I would probably need several extra fields. Taking all this into consideration I have come to the conclusion that creating my own database would probably be the best way to proceed. However I would like to know if this option is the right way to proceed? 
Also are there any easy to use libraries which help me contact an external sql database easily in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should probably have your own backend for something like this. [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1) has a feature called [Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) that makes it easy to write an Android backend and auto-generate an Android code for communicating with it. And it automatically handles the serialization/deserialization, so that you don't need to parse/serialize XML or JSON in order to send the data.